# Notification in all devices

Tags: android, notifications

Below code works perfect in tablet but not in android phone. I want to show notification.

My code is:

```
            if(trigId.equals("0")){
                 intent=new Intent(this,message_detail.class);
            }else{
                 intent=new Intent(this,appinement_list.class);
            }

            PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            //  nt=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Welco0me", System.currentTimeMillis());
            Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Notification From EHIQ").setSound(alarmSound).setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContentText(" "+Helper_MSGNotification.Subject.get(i)).setSmallIcon(aspl.scorehealth.R.drawable.ic_launcher).build();
            NotificationManager manager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            noti.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            manager.notify(i,noti);
```

I am confuse what is actually problem,please help me.

Comment: please tell me which library?

Comment: used `NotificationCompat` instead of `Notification` and add `android-support-v4.jar` into your project

Comment: if you are using eclipse You can add support library right click on project Android Tools-> Add Support Library

Answer (score 1):

The `NotificationCompat.Builder` is the most easy way to create `Notifications` on all Android versions. You can even use features that are available with Android 4.1. If your app runs on devices with Android >=4.1 the new features will be used, if run on Android <4.1 the notification will be an simple old notification.

Simple replace `Notification.Builder` with `NotificationCompat.Builder`, and `import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`.

To create a simple Notification just do:(see [Android API Guide on Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html))

```
NotificationCompat.Builder myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
      .setContentTitle("Exercise of Notification!")
      .setContentText("http://android-er.blogspot.com/")
      .setTicker("Notification!")
      .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
      .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
      .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
      .setAutoCancel(true)
      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
      .build();
```

More Information about [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MYDEMOACTIVITY.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MYDEMOACTIVITY.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Right click on project then choose Android Tools Add support Library Then Install

Changes will be following:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```