# How to create a notification service?

Tags: java, android

Sorry if any of this kind of question has already been posted, i still didnt find the answer that I'm looking for.

My mission is simple - I want to create an app that **pushes a notification** excatly in 9PM.

Here's what I found and what I currently have -

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 6);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
    cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24 , pIntent);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setTicker("Ticker Title")
            .setContentTitle("Content Title")
            .setContentText("Notification content.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
    noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

I herd there has to be a kind of **service** to display the notification. How do I create it? If my code's wrong, feel free to re-make it.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: As of API 19 all calls to setRepeating() will delegate to setInexactRepeating() thus you cannot be sure that it will be fired at 9pm exactly. I'm online with my handset, that's why I can't help you with your code unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside manifest

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".NotifyIntentService" />

<receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>
```

inside Activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 6);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
    cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM); 
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

inside main project

```
   public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
             @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                {
                     Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,
                             NotifyIntentService.class); 
                       startService(serviceIntent);
                 }

    }
```

intent service

```
public class NotifyIntentService extends IntentService
{


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         //your notification code
         //notify();

    }
}
```

[notification in all device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478424/notification-in-all-devices/21478720#21478720)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Not clear about "also declare service" in manifest and what should I put in "onHandleIntent" and how to use the notify() element. Thanks

Comment: inside notify put your notifcation code. below I posted the link  to make notify in all devices

Comment: @user3053246 made my answer a bit clear.not tested but think it should work. for more check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html